# Port opened with ufw marked as closed with nmap

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw, nmap

I'd like to open port 873 on a PC running Ubuntu 16.04. I ssh to this PC, type

```
sudo ufw allow 873
```

Status can be checked with `sudo ufw status`:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
873                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
873 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

However, I don't think the port is open, because

```
nmap localhost -p873
```

returns

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-21 hh:mm EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00017s latency).
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
873/tcp closed rsync

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

Why is it so, and how to actually open port 873?

Comment: Do you actually have rsync running as a daemon process (i.e. is anything currently listening on port 873)?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, I'm running a long `rsync` process right now. From your comment I understand I should wait for it to end and start over again?

Comment: What "long rsync process" exactly? rsync is usually run as a simple command that (if necessary) makes outgoing connections, not as a daemon that listens for incoming connections.

Comment: @steeldriver Based on `htop`, I have no  `rsync` running, as a daemon or else.